Error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'" while copying Python 3 (ipykernel) code on Jupyter Notebook
Copying some code from a course on youtube on quantitative analysis. Copied the exact same code but in my Jupyter Notebook the error in title popped up.
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_ta
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

sp500 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]

sp500['Symbol'] = sp500['Symbol'].str.replace('.','-')

symbols_list = sp500['Symbol'].unique().tolist()

end_date = '2024-10-9'

start_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)-pd.DateOffset(365*8)

df = yf.download(tickers=symbols_list,
                  start=start_date,
                  end=end_date).stack()

df.index.names = ['date', 'ticker']

df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

df['garman_klass_vol'] = ((np.log(df['high'])-np.log(df['low']))**2)/2-(2*np.log(2)-1)*((np.log(df['adj close'])-np.log(df['open']))**2)

df['rsi'] = df.groupby(level=1)['adj close'].transform(lambda x: pandas_ta.rsi(close=x, length = 20))

df['bb_low'] = df.groupby(level=1)['adj close'].transform(lambda x: pandas_ta.bbands(close=np.log1p(x), length=20).iloc[:,0]

df

The error refers to the "pandas_ta.bbands(close=np.log1p(x), length=20).iloc[:,0]". Why does this error only appear on my computer? Different versions? And how could I fix this problem?
Tried deleting the line and the rest of the code runs just fine, but the table expectedly comes without the bb_low column. Using versions Pandas-ta 0.3.14b0 and Pandas 2.2.3.

I faced the same issue with likely the same course. The reason for the error is due to one or more stocks having less than 20 days of 'adj close' prices. This is due to the 20 being passed as length to the bbands functions.
If you use the end_date provided in the course - 2023-09-27, there is no error. This is most likely because there is no new stock with less than 20 days of data in the 8 year range.
I've added a few solutions below to account for this possibility.
Prep code:
sp500 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]

sp500['Symbol'] = sp500['Symbol'].str.replace('.', '-')

symbols_list = sp500['Symbol'].unique().tolist()

end_date = '2024-08-01'
start_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date) - pd.DateOffset(365*8)

df = yf.download(tickers=symbols_list, start=start_date, end=end_date).stack()

df.index.names = ['date', 'ticker']

df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

To find the bad data (stocks with less than 20 days of prices): 
# Check for group sizes
group_sizes = df.groupby(level=1).size()

# Filter groups with size less than the length of the bbands (20)
small_groups = group_sizes[group_sizes < 20]
print("Groups with fewer than 20 rows:\n", small_groups)

Solutions:

Reduce the length for bbands
The default length is 14 so you could do this.
df['bb_low'] = df.groupby(level=1)['adj close'].transform(lambda x: pandas_ta.bbands(close=np.log1p(x)).iloc[:,0])


Remove stocks with length less than 20
df = df.groupby(level=1).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 20)
df['bb_low'] = df.groupby(level=1)['adj close'].transform(lambda x: pandas_ta.bbands(close=np.log1p(x), length=20).iloc[:,0])


Fill bbands result with NaN if group has length less than 20
df['bb_low'] = df.groupby(level=1)['adj close'].transform(lambda x: pandas_ta.bbands(close=np.log1p(x), length=20).iloc[:,0] if len(x) >= 20 else np.nan)




I'm not sure what the ideal solution is since I'm learning quants myself but I chose to go with the 3rd solution for this course.
